# template member of std::pair<> must have const copy constructor. How to implement that constraint

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std-pair

C++11 standard require that the template member of `std::pair<>` must have **const** copy constructor. Otherwise, it would not compile.(from the book *the C++ standard library*, Nicolai M. Josuttis.). So, code below wouldn't compile if it's against c++11 standard:

```
class A{
    int i;
public:
    A(){}
    A(A&){} 
};

int main(){
    pair<int, A> p;
}
```

with `-std=c++11`, the G++ compiler would report error:

> > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1     = int; _T2 = A]' declared to take const reference, but implicit declaration would take non-const:
> >
> > ```
> >             constexpr pair(const pair&) = default
> > ```

That is because we declare A's copy constructor to be non-const. If we change `A(A&){}` to be `A(const A&){}`, or we remove the `-std=c++11` flag, everything would be fine.

My question is, how is that constaint implemented? I can see no support in the language itself that provide us a inside look into the template parameter `T`. I mean, with something declared like this:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class pair{
    ...
    //how do you know whether the constructor of T1 and T2 are const ?
    ...
};
```

How do you know whether the constructor of T1 and T2 is are `const` or not

Answer (score 3):

> //how do you know whether the constructor of T1 and T2 are const ?

You use [std::is_copy_constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible).

Comment: `is_copy_constructible()` checks for the presence of a copy constructor.  It doesn't check that the argument is `const`.

Comment: `is_copy_constructible` checks if the type is constructible by `const T&`. Strictly speaking, the answer should have been to check a combination of `std::is_constructible<T1, T1&>` and `std::is_constructible<T1, const T1&>`;